# newbie: IIS URL Rewrite

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to use IIS URL Rewrite to rewrite:

**platformsite/folder_name_here** to **platformsite.company.com/folder_name_here**

The rule is as follows ({:

```
                <rule name="test" >
                <match url="^platformsite" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.company.com/" />
```

However, this is not working.  404 not found errors is instead what I'm getting.  Forgive me, as I'm new to URL rewrites in IIS so any help will greatly be appreciated.

**Update 10/8**

After following this link https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59, I managed to come up wi/ the following, but still getting the 404.

```
    <rewrite> 
     <rules> 
     <rule name="Rewrite to some page"> 
      <match url="folder_name_here" /> 
       <conditions> 
        <add input="HTTP_HOST" pattern="^platformsite$" /> 
       </conditions> 
       <action type="Redirect" url="platformsite.company.com/folder_name_here"; /> 
     </rule> 
    </rules> 
   </rewrite>
```

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 lesson 1.

Comment: I tried following the link, it was helpful, learned some more stuff, but still having difficulty to get it to work.  I was wondering if you can perhaps take a look at my updated code & see where I possibly went wrong.

Comment: First, there should be no `;`. Second, use `http://platformsite.company.com/folder_name_here` or `https://platformsite.company.com/folder_name_here` based on your situation. Always set complete URL if you change host name. Study HTTP protocol and learn what are the valid URLs.